# Maximise XAML in Visual Studio 2010 designer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, design-time, cider

The Visual Studio designer almost never works with any of my views/pages and I am tired of waiting for it to decide if it is going to (inevitably) fail or not.

I dont even use the VS designer, so I am looking for a way to simply have the XAML section expand by default (without having to open the document in the first place).

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to

**Tools > Options > Text Editor > XAML > Miscellaneous**

There us an option for “Always open documents in full XAML view”.  Check that box:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's possible just check the `"Always open documents in full XAML view"` option in the VS2010 settings..

`Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> XAML - >Miscellaneous -> "Always open documents in full XAML view"`

[image]